# DNS rerouting mydomain.com/mysite.htm to www.mydomain.com

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible to use DNS to take any requests that come from:

mydomain.com

for example:

mydomain.com/mysite/page.htm

to be routed to:

www.mydomain.com

All of the URL after the domain should be removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, DNS just translates hostnames.  You would have to configure your web server to do this.

Comment: thx, not the asnwer we wanted, but who says you get what you want.  Thx.

Comment: It would be pretty easy to configure apache to do this, if needed.